# Alternate method to get Google access token other than URL extraction from browser?

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, cors, google-oauth, google-signin

I am implementing google sign in manually on Reactjs. I am **not** able to **extract** the **accesstoken **returned by google **in the URL**, after all steps due to **"Cross-Origin Policy blocks window..location() calls"** and By luck it works sometimes and gets sent to backend.  My backend team succesfully made apis for converting the access token to Bearer token for Auhtorization into the website.

```
 const oauthSignIn = () => {
    const oauth2Endpoint = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth';
  
    // Parameters to pass to OAuth 2.0 endpoint.
    const params = {
      client_id: 'I have hidden it',
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/profile',
      response_type: 'token',
      scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
      include_granted_scopes: 'true',
      state: 'pass-through value',
    };



    // Build the URL with query parameters
    const queryString = Object.keys(params)
      .map((key) => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(params[key])}`)
      .join('&');

    // Open a new window with the OAuth 2.0 endpoint URL
    // const authWindow = window.open(`${oauth2Endpoint}?${queryString}`, '_blank');

     const authWindow = window.open(`${oauth2Endpoint}?${queryString}`, '_blank');
   
    // Listen for changes in the new window's location
    const checkForAccessToken = async () => {
     
     const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(authWindow.location.hash.substring(1)); 
     const newAccessToken = urlParams.get('access_token');
     const newExpiresIn=urlParams.get('expires_in');
        // If access token is found, set it in the state and close the window
        if (newAccessToken) {
          setAccessToken(newAccessToken);
          localStorage.setItem("accessToken",newAccessToken)
          authWindow.close();
        }
```

I tried it with regex and some URL extraction but it was blocked due to cross origin restrictions , Backedn is ok with Allow Acess to corss origins localhost 3000 , buut still gives this error , and it sometimes go through also by luck . I am attaching remaining code to understand . I included a timer in the end , which seems to do the job sometimes . await and async has no effect on my functions

```
 const backendEndpoint = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/convert-token'; // Replace with your actual backend endpoint
        const backendData = {
          client_id: 'i have hidden it',
          grant_type: 'convert_token',
          client_secret: 'I have hidden it' , // Replace with your actual client secret
          backend: 'google-oauth2',
          token: newAccessToken,
        };
  
        try{
        const response = await axios.post(backendEndpoint, backendData, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json', // Set the content type based on your backend requirements
          },
        });
       
            console.log(response.data);
            localStorage.setItem("BearerToken",response.data.access_token)
            localStorage.setItem("BearerToken_ExpiresIn",response.data.expires_in)
            // Handle the response from your backend as needed
        
            // add } here


        if (newExpiresIn) {
          setExpiresIn(newExpiresIn);
          localStorage.setItem("expiresIn",newExpiresIn)
          //authWindow.close();
        }
       
        // Hiding access token ->Just putting a text in the url
        window.history.pushState({},document.title,"/"+"profile")
        //navigate('/profile')
        authWindow.close();

      } catch (error) {
        // Handle potential errors (e.g., window closed without granting access)
        console.error('Error checking for access token:', error);
      }
      
    };


    // Set up a timer to periodically check the window's location for the access token
     const intervalId = setInterval(checkForAccessToken, 1000);

    // Close the interval after 10 seconds (adjust as needed)
    setTimeout(() => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, 4000);
  };
```